# Why can't I access more than 25 tweets using tweepy search API?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using `tweepy` in Python to search for Tweets.  I'm using `tweepy.api.search()` to query older tweets, and noticed I can't access 500 Tweets at once.  In fact, I can't return more than 25.

I have used both the `count` and `rpp (results per page)` keywords.  What I can't seem to figure out is if I'm just not allowed to access this many tweets at once, or if something is buggy.  Here is my code:

```
for tweet in api.search(q='obama', count=500, show_user=False, rpp=500,
                        geocode='38.899722,-77.048363,500mi'):
    print tweet.created_at, '\n',  tweet.text, '\n\n'
```

This gives me 25 tweets as output.  Here are the first few to show it's working:

```
2015-04-01 16:42:28 
"@JonahMarais: me and Michelle Obama are dating guys"
Lot twist. 
Its April fools day.  


2015-04-01 16:42:05 
"@JonahMarais: me and Michelle Obama are dating guys"
SIKE. 


2015-04-01 16:38:44 
Forget #WinstonChurchill #Obama isn't measuring up to #NevilleChamberlain says http://t.co/6JZqXjUdRH #IranTalks #Israel
```

Comment: How are you authenticating...

Comment: I have a dummy app, and just went on and requested a consumer key and access token the standard way.  The rest just kind of happens automatically in tweepy/twitter, I just pass my keys in I instantiate the api class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get 500 tweets in a single search because the maximum value for the `count` parameter is 100--it defaults to a smaller number if you put in anything larger (or negative). Looking at the `count` parameter in the Twitter API [GET search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) docs:

> **count** - The number of tweets to return per page, up to a maximum of 100.

This means you can't get more than 100 results for a given search. You might want to check out the [Tweepy cursor](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/cursor_tutorial.html) for an easy way to search larger quantities of tweets.